# Express Node JS POST. How do I add values to my req.body without using url parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, post

I'm building a rest api using Express NodeJS with mysql.  I'm having no issues at all using `GET` and using `req.params.value` and passing values using URL parameters.

Now I'm trying to use `POST` to insert some data into my database.  Using POSTMAN I have no problems doing this because obviously you can set the BODY variables to be used.  But it dawned on me in my applications I won't be able to use POSTMAN to do this.  My quesiton (which may be silly) is how do I pass these BODY variables to my api?  Do I still pass them through the url as parameters?  If so, would I use `req.body.value` or `req.params.value`?  Here is my `POST` code:

```
// Add new record 
router.post('/editablerecords/add', function (req, res) {

    let qb_TxnID = req.body.txnid
    let type = req.body.type;
    let margin = req.body.margin;

    if (!qb_TxnID || !type || !margin ) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error:true, message: 'Please provide qb_TxnID, type, or margin' });
    }

    // res.send(qb_TxnID + ' ' + type + ' ' + margin);

    connection.query("INSERT INTO pxeQuoteToClose SET ? ", { 'qb_TxnID': qb_TxnID, 'type': type, 'margin': margin }, function (error, results, fields) {
        if(error){
            res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null})); 
            //If there is error, we send the error in the error section with 500 status
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ error: false, data: results, message: 'New record has been created successfully.' }));
            //If there is no error, all is good and response is 200OK.
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: you can set a json payload.. not sure the api call off top but a quick google search should get you sorted

Comment: Parameters passed in a POST request would be in `req.body`

Comment: @PrerakSola so would I still need to setup the parameters in my post?  For example:  `router.post('/editablerecords/add/:txnid&:type', function (req, res) {`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you extract POST data in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js)

Comment: @drpcken No. You'll declare `router.post('/editablerecords/add')` and the `req` object in the function will have the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on how you will make your request, as an XMLHttpRequest call or via a form, but it will definitely not be using params in that case. Here are three options to send data to your API depending on your requirement, in your case I would advice the last one.

1 - You can use a form and make the action point to to your endpoint. In that case you'll have to add a bodyParser middleware for x-www-form-urlencoded data to your express application. If your using the `body-parser` library it is as simple as `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded([options]))`. Data will be available in `req.body`.

2 - You can send all data in your url but in the query string, not the params. For example: `https://yourapi.com/editablerecords/add?qb_TxnID=data_id&type=data_type&margin=data_margin`. All data will then be available in the `req.query` object. No need to add any parser.

3 - Last but not least, I would advise to send your data as a json body using an XMLHttpRequest. To help you out you may use a library like `axios` or  `fecth` but the principle stay the same: you set your body with your data object and you retrieve it on `req.body`on your api. Seeing your code I do assume that your are using a body parser but if that would not be the case, you should add a middleware using `app.use(bodyParser.json())`.

I hope I have answer your question and that it will help you out.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'll look into #3.  I am using body parser actually!  I will look into XMLHttpRequest.  I'm very new to building my own API but it's fascinating.  Thank you